# extracting zipcode from html file using python

Tags: python

I want to extract us Zipcode from sec 10k html files using python

I have tried this code

```
import re
s="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20/000095012310024631/c97665e10vk.htm"

zipcode = re.findall(r'\b[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?\b', s)
print zipcode
```

output is  []
whereas I need 08071-0888

Comment: You're searching in the URL, not the files.

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html, then find the zip code using `regex` if necessary

Comment: You are searching in url. First grab the html code with for given url and then search inside html. You can use this regex too, `r'([0-9]{5}?-[0-9]{4})'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. First, grab the html using `BeautifulSoup`. Find all `td` tag in the html. Then, extract the zipcode using `regex`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20/000095012310024631/c97665e10vk.htm"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for s in soup.find_all("td", attrs={"align":"center"}):
    zipcode = re.findall("(\d{5}-\d{4})",str(s)) # you can also use your regex if you want
    if zipcode != []:
        print (zipcode)
```

Output:

```
['08071-0888']
```

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks for your help, I have to extract zip and city info from number of files in folder, my code is like below but will change according to your regex. next thing is to extract city information and save them to csv file[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld0Cg.png)

Comment: Ok good. Ask me if you have some troubles. But please put your comment in comment section, not as an answer.